# Is there a .net framework method to generate a collection from a property of all items in a collection?

Tags: .net, list, collections

I have

```
myObjects = List(of myObject)
```

myObject has

```
Public Property myProperty as string
```

Is there a framework method to produce

```
myObjectProperties = List(of string)
```

from each `myObject.myProperty` in `myObjects`?

Obviously I can easily create one. I'm just wondering if there's a framework solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq:

```
myObjectProperties = myObjects.Select(x => x.myProperty).ToList()
```

(sorry, it's C# and not VB.NET, but you are just talking about .NET ...)

Comment: Technically speaking, that isn't LINQ?  But kudos for a fast example :-) I was thinking this as an answer, but couldn't type the syntax fast enough lol

Comment: All this is in the system.Linq namespace and reflects the possibilities of Linq, so it is often called "Linq"... I don't know how correct or wrong it is.

Comment: no worries mate I was just nit-picking for the sake of the answer.  I believe LINQ to be just the keyword-syntax and compiler support.  Your example is a lambda statement, just as useful to know about, and as you say in the LINQ namespace as an addition to support LINQ.  Also as you know, what LINQ will be spat out as.

Answer (score 2):

And here's the VB version of @Stefan Steinegger's code:

```
Dim myObjectProperties = myObjects.Select(Function(F) F.myProperty).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the LINQ solution posted by others, you can use also use the [**`ConvertAll`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) instance method on the [**`List(Of T)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class to eagerly create a new list based on a projection.

```
Dim myObjectProperties = myObjects.ConvertAll(Function(m) m.myProperty)
```